# I need to transpose some columns in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, transpose

I have the following Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyGZQEAuY6_YMtPGR3oUykjArTiQ6OK82A-YCrnEuxI/edit#gid=0

Every month I add a new month's data in the first sheet and I need to automate the structure to make it look like the 2nd sheet somehow. The month columns need to turn into rows so I could visualise it properly in Looker Studio.

I am open to slightly restructure the first sheet, use any formulas out there or use an app script.

Would you please guide me? thanks.

I tried to transpose it but it just switched the columns with rows

Comment: Quick question, I can see that there are some `change` columns on the 1st sheet, but none in your expected output in the 2nd sheet; just want to ask if those `change` columns are needed or they can be removed/disregarded?

Comment: They should remain in the first sheet but i do not need them in the second. @MicTest

Comment: Your question must stand on its own. Please don't assume that users can/must/will open your spreadsheet to better understand your question; all this information should be included in the body of your question. Would you please edit your question to explain your scenario, your data and include sample data as well as an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one `generalized approach` you may improvise on to fit your needs:*

```js
=let(Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),Sheet1!D1:1,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(regexmatch(c,join("|",index(text(edate(0,sequence(12)),"mmmm")))),hstack(Sheet1!C2:C,scan(,Sheet1!A2:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),wrapcols(c,rows(Sheet1!A2:A),c),filter(indirect("Sheet1!D2:"&rows(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!D1:1=c)),)))),
     filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>"",index(Σ,,1)<>"Total Page likes",index(Σ,,4)<>""))
```

[image]